# When len() judges variables, it prompts TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, list, typeerror

get_magnet_hash() returns None or a list of 0~n elements.

```
def get_magnet(detail_url):
    magnet = get_magnet_hash(detail_url)
    print(type(magnet))
    if magnet != None:
        if len(magnet) == 0:
            return None
        return 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:'+magnet[0]
    return None
```

The `if len(magnet) == 0:return None` here is redundant, but I can only write it like this. If it is written as follows, then the code will prompt TypeError after running.

```
def get_magnet(detail_url):
    magnet = get_magnet_hash(detail_url)
    print(type(magnet))
    # This is wrong
    if (magnet != None) & (len(magnet) != 0):
        return 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:'+magnet[0]
    return None
```

I can't understand here, I'm a beginner in Python, can someone help me?

I'm hoping someone will tell me what's going on here, and why using a cleaner structure doesn't work? thank you!

Comment: because `&` is the bitwise and, you want to use the logical and which is just `and`. Using `&` will be incorrect even in C language, which I assume is where you got the & from

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I think I already know why. I confused the role of `&` and `and`, thank you